# How to catch touch events in javascript in Chrome and MSIE10 using touch screen

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, touch, draggable

I want my web application to work using draggable objects on Windows devices with touch screen but the new Chrome and new MSIE 10 do not let me use the dragging developed for mouse anymore.  So this http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ works with mouse but does not work with touch.

How to make draggable work with touch in Chrome and MSIE 10?

Comment: If you run `document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) { console.log(e) }, false)` would your device print anything to the console on tap? If it does, you can emulate mouse events pretty easily.

Comment: chrome support touchstart and touchend but not touchmove given this test https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events but interesting that it actually does not seem to work in firefox 13 anymore...
live demo: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/touchevents.html

Comment: Try an isolated test here: http://jsfiddle.net/6QkB7/

Comment: Chrome fires touch start and touch end, not touch move, Firefox does not fire anything

Comment: MSIE 10 also does not fire any touch event

Answer (score 3):

Chrome on Windows 7 [doesn't yet support touch events](http://caniuse.com/touch)

However in Chrome 20+ you can navigate to experimental chrome://flags and turn on 'Enable touch events' to get TouchStart/Move/End events firing, but it does seem to break other behaviour like pinch zoom and finger scrolling.

With this flag disabled, TouchStart/End are misfiring due to [this bug in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131659)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for "swipe" events, take a look at [jQuery++ library](http://jquerypp.com/#swipe). take a look at the link I provided for a demo.

> jQuery.event.swipe adds support for swipe motions providing the delegatable swipeleft, swiperight, swipedown, swipeup and swipe events:

Comment: nope, does not work. Firefox supports only drag but Chrome does not support any drag or swipe

Comment: I just checked the jQuery++ swipe event handler and it works both in Firefox 12 and chromium 20 in windows and Ubuntu (chromium 18).

Comment: I was able to do it in the end with Firefox (like on the tenth swipe) but I am not able to do it in Chrome 19 in Windows 7 with touch screen (it just keeps moving the whole page). MSIE 10 on Windows 8 does not work either. What I do is simply touching the green area and move my finger to some direction and release and it does not react

Comment: so when I open the jsfiddle in a whole windows so there is no page dragging, firefox can register up and down as well but when there is a possibility of dragging the whole page in Firefox, it does that instead of down or up events. Ive learned to do it in Firefox on first try... before it did not occur to me that I actually cant leave the green area with my finger. In chrome it still does not work even in the whole jsfiddle window and not even when I added ev.preventDefault(); I think that Firefox does not fire it as touch events but as mouse events though.